# leveldb error: undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc

I download and build leveldb according to this [README](https://github.com/google/leveldb), and then properly add `libleveldb.a` and the `include/leveldb` directory (header files) to my environment path.

My test code:

```cpp
/*leveldb_test.cpp
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <leveldb/db.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    leveldb::DB* db;
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;

    leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "./testdb", &db);
    assert(status.ok());

    return 0;
}
```

And I compile it as:

```
g++ leveldb_test.cpp -o leveldb_test -lpthread -lleveldb -std=c++11
```

It produces "undefined reference" errors:

```
leveldb_test.o: In function `main':
leveldb_test.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::DB**)'
leveldb_test.cpp:(.text+0x29e): undefined reference to `leveldb::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem?

My environment: `Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 - gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 - Red Hat 4.8.3-9`

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Seems it cannot find the library path, try to use `-L` like described [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html).

Comment: @karastojko the lib path is fine, otherwise the error would be `No such file or directory` at `#include<leveldb/db.h>`...Anyway I also tried link in an explicit way, but did not work

Comment: The linker is complaining, thus it cannot find the library, the same example is on the given [link](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html). If you have set PATH it is not considered by Gcc, check the list [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html). Try to copy the library files in the same directory where your code resides and check if it's being found.